# Setting global variables in jasmine for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an angular application with some global environment variables defined in an env.js file:

```
(function(sp) {
'use strict';

pk.env = pk.env || {};

// localhost
pk.env.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';
})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? (this.pk = this.pk || {}) : exports);
```

These variables are used in multiple factories to make REST API calls:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('pkApp').factory('pkFactory', PKFactory);

function PKFactory($http) {
    var urlBase = pk.env.baseUrl;
    var apiUrl = 'v1/data';
    var _pkFactory = {};

    _pkFactory.getData = function() {
        return $http.get(urlBase + apiUrl);
    };


    return _pkFactory;
}
```

I am writing unit tests for this factory using Jasmine and I keep getting the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: pk

If I remove this variable reference from the factory, the tests run fine.

```
'use strict';

console.log('=== In pk.factory.spec');

describe('Unit: pkFactory', function() {

  beforeEach(module("pkApp"));

  var $httpBackend, $rootScope, pkFactory;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    // Set up the mock http service responses
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'v1/data').respond('Not found');

    pkFactory = $injector.get('pkFactory');

  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('expects getData method to be defined', function(){
    expect(pkFactory.getData()).toBeDefined();
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
})
```

How do I inject value of 'pk.env.baseUrl' into the factory? I have tried using $window, but it didn't work.

Comment: looks like you have declared environment variables in IIFE function that will restrict scope of it.

Comment: So are you saying I should convert this to an angular constant or value?

Comment: yes...otherwise you need to make it global thing without wrapping it into IIFE pattern?

Comment: So I removed the IIFE wrapper, and tried setting the values using $window and it still doesn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I added this: module(function($provide) {
    var pk = {}
    pk.env = {};
    pk.env.baseUrl = '';

    $provide.value('$window', pk);
  });

Comment: you should use `(function($provide) { var pk = {} pk.env = {}; pk.env.baseUrl = ''; $provide.value('pk', pk); });` while using it you need to `$injector.get('pk')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid using the globals in Angular completely.

Convert the file to an angular value or constant:

```
angular.module('pkApp').value('pk', pk);
```

now you can change `pkFactory` to get the `pk` object injected

```
function PKFactory($http, pk) {
    // pk is no longer from global scope, but injected from angular as an argument
    var urlBase = pk.env.baseUrl;
    var apiUrl = 'v1/data';
    var _pkFactory = {};

    _pkFactory.getData = function() {
        return $http.get(urlBase + apiUrl);
    };


    return _pkFactory;
}
```

and in tests, you can now mock the pk to a different value (or not do anything and use the one from code)

Answer (score 6):

As pretty much already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263586/global-variables-in-karma-test-runner), you can also declare a global variable within your test file

```
var globalVar = "something";

describe('Your test suit', function() {
    ...
});
```

and if you are using Karma you can edit the `karma.conf.js` file to define it

```
 // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
 files: [
    ...,
    'file-containing-the-global-variable.js'
 ],
```