# Karma in AngularJS not working on a controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up a simple test with Karma. I'm using AngularJS for this small test.

**Controller (test.controller.js)**:

```
class TestController{
    constructor($scope, $window, $localStorage){
    'ngInject'
        this.name = "TestController";
        $localStorage.testVariable = 'ola';
    }
}
export default TestController;
```

**Test file (test.spec.js)**

```
describe('Test', () => {
    let $rootScope, makeController, $scope, $window, $localStorage;
    beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_, _$window_, _$localStorage_) => {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $window = _$window_;
        $localStorage = _$localStorage_;
        makeController = () => {
            return new TestController($scope, $window, $localStorage);
        };
    }));

    describe('Controller', () => {
        it('has a name property', () => {
            let controller = makeController();
            expect(controller).to.have.property('name');
        });
    });
});
```

After I run **karma start**, I get the following response:

```
 Test
     Controller
     x has a name property
         TypeError: Cannot read property 'testVariable' of undefined
```

It seems like that **Karma** is having a conflict with $localStorage.

If I remove all the $localStorage elements, Karma will return success.

Is it possible to help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think its not a good idea to use `$localStorage` in unit test. as it is browser dependent. What you can do is manually assign `testVariable` object to `$localStorage` and make ur test go ahead with other checks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you, but I have multiple controllers and most of them make use of localStorage. How can I ignore localStorage for my tests? Karma is blocking its  process when detecting a localStorage variable, and all I want is to ignore that variable in order to make it work. How can assign it manually on spec.js file?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263586/global-variables-in-karma-test-runner. Try to declare the variable on global level. I dont think you can ignore that variable

Comment: Oh, but assume that I have a large Number of localStorage.X variables on my controllers. Does it make sense to assign each one globally? Thank you in advance. Your help and ideas are really appreciated!

Comment: No, it should be assigned to the `controller.spec` files rather than assigning at global level. Reason being, you are writing unit test. its specific to a single controller. Also, you may also want to write cases where **either** the `localstorage` is undefined and you would expect `.undefined()` **OR** when the value is incorrect and your test condition should test those failures

Comment: I tried to set testVariable on localStorage (as you said) but without success. It gives me the same error over and over again.. It seems that testVariable is not successfuly attached to localStorage