# How to mock a globally exported function

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am writing a karma unit test against my Angular component. I ran into a situation and I don't know how to proceed. I googled and found...nothing.

In another file, I have a globally exported function defined:

```
export function findServices(
    serviceType: OptionValue | undefined,
    procedureCode: ProcedureCode | undefined,
    state: ServiceProcedureAuthorizationState
): ServiceProcedureAuthorizationService[] {
}
```

Suffice it to say that it uses state from the store to return answers to this query. I'd rather not set all of this up for my unit test. I want to mock it somehow.

Here is the call in my angular component.

```
private setAuthState(group: SpServiceGroup, authorizationState: ServiceProcedureAuthorizationState) {
    const services: ServiceProcedureAuthorizationService[] = findServices(
        group.serviceType,
        group.procedureCode,
        authorizationState
    );
```

How do I mock this?

Someone pointed out trying: [Global variables in Karma test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263586/global-variables-in-karma-test-runner) so I attempted to create a function in my test file:

```
export function findServices(
    serviceType: OptionValue | undefined,
    procedureCode: ProcedureCode | undefined,
    state: ServiceProcedureAuthorizationState
): ServiceProcedureAuthorizationService[] {
    console.log('returning services');
    return services;
}
```

But it continues to run the one from the production file. So that is not the solution.

Comment: `findServices` isn't a global function? Your exporting it, so it needs to be imported to run, that's not global

Comment: @Liam-ReinstateMonica Then what is it?

Comment: It's an exported function. The JS that this produces is inside a closure, a global variable would be on the global object (i.e. `window.funct()`)

Comment: Why isn't this inside a service? That seems to be the right "angular" thing to do here. Then you mock it like you do any other service. By importing the function directly your bypassing the dependency injection rolled into angular. All dependencies should be injected into the constructor so that you don't get this issue when unit testing

Comment: @Liam-ReinstateMonica I didn't write the code, I'm merely unit testing it, but, as I indicated in my question, I believe this uses state that is part of the store. Stores are cool, but they use these globally exported functions a bit. Seems like kind of a design issue.

Comment: @Liam-ReinstateMonica is globally exported function better?

Comment: Like I said, you can't inject a service that isn't getting injected. The developer of this code has essentially hard coded this. The solution is to fix that

Comment: Because this returns store state, it occurred to me over the weekend that it should use the store interface, send a message, and return the results as state. This would prevent the issue I'm having.

Another example of why you should write your tests first. If that had happened, untestable code would never have been written. :(